# Label and ticks of colorbar is not in the mp4 created by animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib-3d

Recently, I have been learning how to use animation in the matplotlib package. I combined and modified code from the following two websites：

[website1](https://pythonmatplotlibtips.blogspot.com/2018/01/rotate-azimuth-angle-animation-3d-python-matplotlib-pyplot.html)

[website2](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/box3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-box3d-py)

The code is here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def init():
    return fig
def animate(i):
    # azimuth angle : 0 deg to 360 deg
    ax.view_init(elev=10, azim=i*4)
    return fig
# Define dimensions
Nx, Ny, Nz = 100, 300, 500
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(Nx), np.arange(Ny), -np.arange(Nz))

# Create fake data
data = (((X+100)**2 + (Y-20)**2 + 2*Z)/1000+1)

kw = {
    'vmin': data.min(),
    'vmax': data.max(),
    'levels': np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), 10),
}

# Create a figure with 3D ax
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax = Axes3D(fig)

# Plot contour surfaces

_ = ax.contourf(
    X[:, :, 0], Y[:, :, 0], data[:, :, 0],
    zdir='z', offset=Z.min(), **kw
)

_ = ax.contourf(
    X[:, :, -1], Y[:, :, -1], data[:, :, -1],
    zdir='z', offset=Z.max(), **kw
)

_ = ax.contourf(
    X[0, :, :], data[0, :, :], Z[0, :, :],
    zdir='y', offset=Y.min(), **kw
)

_ = ax.contourf(
    X[-1, :, :], data[-1, :, :], Z[-1, :, :],
    zdir='y', offset=Y.max(), **kw
)

D = ax.contourf(
    data[:, 0, :], Y[:, 0, :], Z[:, 0, :],
    zdir='x', offset=X.min(), **kw
)

C = ax.contourf(
    data[:, -1, :], Y[:, -1, :], Z[:, -1, :],
    zdir='x', offset=X.max(), **kw
)

# --


# Set limits of the plot from coord limits
xmin, xmax = X.min(), X.max()
ymin, ymax = Y.min(), Y.max()
zmin, zmax = Z.min(), Z.max()
ax.set(xlim=[xmin, xmax], ylim=[ymin, ymax], zlim=[zmin, zmax])

# Plot edges
edges_kw = dict(color='0.4', linewidth=1, zorder=1e3)
ax.plot([xmax, xmax], [ymin, ymax], zmax, **edges_kw)
ax.plot([xmax, xmax], [ymin, ymax], zmin, **edges_kw)
ax.plot([xmin, xmin], [ymin, ymax], zmax, **edges_kw)
ax.plot([xmin, xmin], [ymin, ymax], zmin, **edges_kw)


ax.plot([xmin, xmax], [ymin, ymin], zmin, **edges_kw)
ax.plot([xmin, xmax], [ymax, ymax], zmin, **edges_kw)
ax.plot([xmin, xmax], [ymin, ymin], zmax, **edges_kw)
ax.plot([xmin, xmax], [ymax, ymax], zmax, **edges_kw)

ax.plot([xmax, xmax], [ymin, ymin], [zmin, zmax], **edges_kw)
ax.plot([xmin, xmin], [ymin, ymin], [zmin, zmax], **edges_kw)
ax.plot([xmax, xmax], [ymax, ymax], [zmin, zmax], **edges_kw)
ax.plot([xmin, xmin], [ymax, ymax], [zmin, zmax], **edges_kw)


# Set zoom and angle view
#ax.view_init(40, -30, x)
ax.set_box_aspect(None, zoom=0.9)
ax.set_box_aspect(None, zoom=0.9)

# Colorbar
fig.colorbar(D, ax=ax, fraction=0.02, pad=0.05, orientation = 'vertical', location = 'right')


plt.savefig("surfaceplot.png",bbox_inches='tight')
# Show Figure


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=90, interval=50)
fn = 'rotate_elevation_angle_3d_surf'
ani.save(fn+'.mp4',writer='ffmpeg',fps=1000/50)
ani.save(fn+'.gif',writer='imagemagick',fps=1000/50)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

After running the above code, corresponding mp4, gif, and png files can be generated. However, currently, the colorbar in the mp4 and gif files only display the colorbar itself, without the corresponding tick labels and data. The png file, on the other hand, does include these contents.

[The .png result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bNZL.png)

[The .gif result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cUI6.gif)

How can I make sure that the mp4 and gif files also display the corresponding tick labels and data?

Comment: Can you explain what happens if you uncomment the line `ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')` and comment ax = Axes3D(fig)?

Comment: @Diego: Thank you very much, the replacement works! May I ask, what is the difference between the two methods? When I was modifying the code, I only saw one plot, so I thought using "subplot" might not be appropriate, which is why I used "Axes3D" instead.

Comment: ax.set_box_aspect(None, zoom=0.9) ---> does changing zoom value has any influence ???

Comment: @pippo1980 I tried to modify it, and it did not...

Comment: @haotianyi I don't know what the particular issue is, but it may have something to do with the following warning message: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Axes3D(fig) adding itself to the figure is deprecated since 3.4... which I got trying to run your code. Also, the subplot functions allow you to create multiple subplots, but they can equally well handle single plots.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace
`ax = Axes3D(fig)` by
`ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')`.
This answer is provided by Diego.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).